# Can I jump over monsters while using the charge jump granted by pouncing armor?

Tags: dnd-4e, barbarian, charge

I'm wondering if a barbarian with pouncing armor and an ability score of 17 in athletics can feasibly jump over a monster to reach the monsters behind as part of the charge jump allowed by the pouncing armor.

Answer (score 7):

No. The problem is you can't get enough loft to avoid an opportunity attack (why you're trying to jump in the first place).

To get the distance you clear vertically, you divide the check by 10 and add two. Your *maxium* distance cleared vertically is 37/10 + 2 = 5. This means you are 1 square above the ground, that's enough (if you get a 13 or higher) to clear a short medium monster, but not enough to avoid an opportunity attack as you move past.

If you're looking for monster avoidance, the L2+ neck slot item Badge of the Beserker is the proper one. Pouncing armor is either to extend your movement (your max range becomes 7 here), or to reach a lowish flying enemy (prepare for a fall though).

Comment: thanks for your answer I feared it would turn out like that. also the suggestion of badge of the beserker is very much appreciated though i dont think it would allow me to move through the square of the monster to reach the back lines or can characters actually move through monster squares?

Comment: @KriekvanderMeulen no, you can't move through, but usually moving past is enough, charges don't have to be straight lines, the only requirement is that each square of movement take you closer, so you can charge in banana type curve to go around enemies. The jump your considering is this exact move, just on the vertical axis rather than a horizontal one.

Comment: Thanks alot for clearing that up! My party and I thought that charges could only be made in straight lines

Comment: @KriekvanderMeulen full charge rules here: http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=324. (Thats RC 240 or PHB 287)